# How to give the proof or counterexample?

Tags: statistics, optimization

**Original Problem:** Consider a Balanced Transportation problem (BTP) with costs $c_{ij}$ . Suppose $c_{11}$ is the largest cost in the table (i.e. $c_{11} = \max \limits_{i,j} c_{ij}$ ). Must $x_{11} = 0$ in every optimal solution? Explain! (Make sure to state “yes” or “no”, and give a short proof or a counterexample.)

I said yes because BTP problems always seek to minimize, but I don't know how to give a simple counterexample. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: I added optimisation as a tag, since the problem does remind me of (linear) optimisation. Not currently on that wavelength, so can't recall relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is no.  Hint to help you construct a small counterexample: $3+0<2+2$.

Comment: why is it no?? And where does 3 + 0 > 2 + 2 come from?

Comment: Second hint: the counterexample I'm suggesting has two supply nodes and two demand nodes, with $c_{1,1}=3$.